# Traefik /auth proxy to CAS server

Tags: authentication, go, cas, http-redirect, traefik

I am trying to use [Traefik's forward authentication](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#forward-authentication) for SSO my docker applications. Indeed we already have a CAS server in company and the idea would be to reuse it. I understand that I can not directly point Traefic to the CAS server (the redirect to login is considered as an answer, other than 2XX login failed). I can write a small proxy in Golang for example to forward  the request to CAS, a bit like [here](https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth)

My question is whether or not it is possible? If yes a flow schema would be welcome and any other help to realize the project.